# What is focusing and how do I use it?

Tags: terminology, focusing

I have heard the term "focusing" with respect to the sequent calculus (System LK) and related calculi like the $\bar{\lambda} \mu \tilde{\mu}$-calculus. What is focusing and how do I use it?

It seems to be something like a method for disambiguating which value on the right side of a sequent to operate on?

The topic also seems to pop up with respect to operational semantics, polarization and linear logic.

See https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/713/153 for a related question.

I was reminded of focusing while working on a relational language. I had the idea of a theorem $P \vdash_{\Gamma, [\tau]} Q$ over free variables $\Gamma$ becoming a map between $P, Q\colon \Gamma \nrightarrow \tau $. I'm not really sure this is related to focusing in the sequent calculus though.

Comment: Of interest: nLab [focusing](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/focusing)